# Inbound Email messaging service .. If check

Tags: apex

I'm having difficulties in my Apex class that converts a inbound email to a Account, Contact, Opportunity...

It works fine apart from when I get to a if statement (Checking if the email in the body matches any contacts in the database)

I would like it to create the records if no one was found with a matching email...
Else.. Just create the Opp and link it to that contact.

at the minute its just duplicating the records each time even if a contact/account exists I just create a new one.

Here is my Class...

```apex
global class DevelopmentReadyParser implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{
    /*
    * Method Name : handleInbound
    * Description : This method is used to create Account / Contact and Appraisal/Enquiry record
    */
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(
        Messaging.InboundEmail email, 
        Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope
    ) {
        // Create an inboundEmailResult object for returning 
        // the result of the email service.
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        System.debug('---Inside handleInbound------');
        
        String htmlBodyTemplate = email.htmlBody;
        String emailBody = htmlBodyTemplate.stripHtmlTags();
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Id, Email, Name FROM Contact WHERE Email =: emailBody.substringBetween('Email: ', 'Phone') LIMIT 1];

        // Check if contact list is returning 0 contacts! If no contacts are found Create Account+Contact+opportunity
        if (conList.isEmpty()) { 
            String accname =emailBody.substringBetween('Name: ', 'Email');
            String accdes = emailBody.substringBetween('Message: ', 'Office');
            Account ac = new Account(Name = accname, description = accdes);
            insert ac;
            
            string conname = emailBody.substringBetween('Name: ', 'Email');
            string[] nameSplit = conname.split('\\ ');
            String conDescription = 'Development Ready Email Enquiry';
            string conemail = emailBody.substringBetween('Email: ', 'Phone');
            String conPhone = emailBody.substringBetween('Phone: ', 'User');
            Contact con = new Contact(AccountId = ac.Id, Description= conDescription, Phone = conPhone,     MobilePhone = conPhone, FirstName = nameSplit[0],  Email = conemail, LastName = nameSplit[1] );
            insert con;
       
            String listingId;
            String fullname = emailBody.substringBetween('Name: ', 'Email');
            String contactemail = emailBody.substringBetween('Email: ', 'Phone');
            String comments = emailBody.substringBetween('Message: ', 'Office');
            String phone = emailBody.substringBetween('Phone: ', 'User');
            String propertyAddress = emailBody.substringBetween('Address: ', ',' );
            String propLink = emailBody.substringBetween('Property: ', 'Subject');
            String subject = emailBody.substringBetween('Subject: ', 'Message');
            String Search ='%'+propertyAddress+'%';
            // Search for Property Address in message body. IF matches first line off address in data base link opportunity to Listing Id!

            List<PropertyListing__c> PropId =[SELECT Id FROM PropertyListing__c WHERE Property_Address__c LIKE :Search];
            if (!PropId.isEmpty()) {
                listingId = propId.get(0).Id;
            }
        
            Opportunity__c oppObj = new Opportunity__c(
                Name = fullname,
                Description__c = 'subject: '+ subject+' Comments: '+comments +' Property Link: '+propLink,
                Property_Listing__c = listingId,
                Email__c = contactemail,
                Phone__c = phone,
                Source__c = 'Email',
                Contact__c = con.Id,
                Account__c = ac.Id);
            insert oppObj;
                          
            result.success = true;
        }
        // If Contact was found Just create Opportunity linked to found contact ID...
        else {
            String listingId;
            String fullname = emailBody.substringBetween('Name: ', 'Email');
            String contactemail = emailBody.substringBetween('Email: ', 'Phone');
            String comments = emailBody.substringBetween('Message: ', 'Office');
            String phone = emailBody.substringBetween('Phone: ', 'User');
            String propertyAddress = emailBody.substringBetween('Address: ', ',' );
            String propLink = emailBody.substringBetween('Property: ', 'Subject');
            String subject = emailBody.substringBetween('Subject: ', 'Message');
            String Search ='%'+propertyAddress+'%';
                             
            List<PropertyListing__c> PropId =[SELECT Id FROM PropertyListing__c WHERE Property_Address__c LIKE :Search];
            if (!PropId.isEmpty()) {
                listingId = propId.get(0).Id;
            }                      
            
            Opportunity__c oppObj = new Opportunity__c(
                Name = fullname,
                Description__c = 'subject: '+ subject+' Comments: '+comments +'    Property Link: '+propLink,
                Property_Listing__c = listingId,
                Email__c = contactemail,
                Phone__c = phone,
                Contact__c = conList.get(0).Id,
                Source__c = 'Email');
            insert oppObj;
            result.success = true;
        }
        return result;
    } 
}
```

Any Help would on where i'm going wrong would be fantastic!!

Answer (score 0):

Basically the main issue boiled down to white spaces in the email body we were parsing... even though you couldn't see them in the normal Body of the email after banging a `.trim()` on the email we were querying the class worked as expected.

Updated:

```apex
global class DevelopmentReadyParser implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler{
   /*
    * Method Name : handleInbound
    * Description : This method is used to create Lead and Appraisal/Enquiry record
    */
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(
        Messaging.InboundEmail email, 
        Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope
    ) {
        // Create an inboundEmailResult object for returning 
        // the result of the email service.
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        System.debug('---Inside handleInbound------');
        String htmlBodyTemplate = email.htmlBody;
        String emailBody = htmlBodyTemplate.stripHtmlTags();
        String fullname = emailBody.substringBetween('Name: ', 'Email');
        String contactemail = emailBody.substringBetween('Email: ', 'Phone:');
        String comments = emailBody.substringBetween('Message: ', 'Office');
        String phone = emailBody.substringBetween('Phone: ', 'User');
        String propertyAddress = emailBody.substringBetween('Address: ', ',' );
        String propLink = emailBody.substringBetween('Property: ', 'Subject');
        String subject = emailBody.substringBetween('Subject: ', 'Message');
        String search ='%'+propertyAddress+'%';
        String des = emailBody.substringBetween('Message: ', 'Office');
        string[] nameSplit = fullname.split('\\ ');
        String conDescription = 'Development Ready Email Enquiry';
                    
        List<Contact> contactEmailList = [SELECT Id,
                LastName,
                AccountId,
                Email,
                Description  
            FROM Contact 
            WHERE Email LIKE: contactemail.trim()
            LIMIT 1];
        List<PropertyListing__c> propertyListing = [SELECT Id,
                Name
            FROM PropertyListing__c 
            WHERE Property_Address__c LIKE: search
            LIMIT 1];
        if( contactEmailList.isEmpty()) {   
            //Create Account
            Account accountObj = new Account();
            accountObj.Name = fullname;
            accountObj.Description = contactemail;
            //insert Account
            insert accountObj;
    
            //Create Contact
            Contact contactObj = new Contact();
            contactObj.AccountId = accountObj.Id;
            contactObj.FirstName = nameSplit[0];
            contactObj.LastName =nameSplit[1];
            contactObj.Description = des;
            contactObj.HomePhone = phone;
            contactObj.MobilePhone = phone;
            contactObj.Phone = phone;
            contactObj.Email = contactemail;
            contactObj.LeadSource = 'Email';
            //insert Contact
            insert contactObj;
    
            Opportunity__c oppObj = new Opportunity__c();
            oppObj.Name = fullname+''+propertyAddress;
            oppObj.Description__c = conDescription+': '+comments;
            oppObj.Email__c = contactemail;
            oppObj.Phone__c = phone;
            oppObj.Contact__c = contactObj.Id;
            oppObj.Account__c = accountObj.Id;
            if( propertyListing.size()>0) { 
                oppObj.Property_Listing__c = propertyListing[0].Id;}
                insert oppObj;
            } else{
                Opportunity__c oppObj = new Opportunity__c();
                oppObj.Name = fullname+' '+propertyAddress;
                oppObj.Description__c = conDescription+': '+comments;
                oppObj.Email__c = contactemail;
                oppObj.Phone__c = phone;
                oppObj.Contact__c = contactEmailList[0].Id;
                oppObj.Account__c = contactEmailList[0].AccountId;
                if( propertyListing.size()>0) { 
                    oppObj.Property_Listing__c = propertyListing[0].Id;}
                    insert oppObj;
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
```